# Simple C program prints a variable as 6356748 consistently after the variable is supposed to scanf 'd in

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm writing a program and I want to prompt the user to input a number value, and then print the value right after. The issue is that regardless of the number I type, the variable always prints as 6356748.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int days;
    printf("How many days will you be observing your crew?\n");
    scanf("%d",&days);
    printf("%d\n",&days);
    return 0;
}
```

The return is the same for any input (even letters); It just does the print f, takes a user input, and returns 6356748.

I've looked around at other similar posts about this sort of issue, but no luck. 
I've also tried initializing the variable when it is defined and defining the variable outside of the main function. I've also tried adding 1 to the variable after it is scanned in and printing the new value, but that just returns the same value, unchanged: 6356748.
I think it's my code because I tried this code in an online IDE, but I don't know how it would be because the syntax seems fine to me.

I want to know how to make the scanf actually assign the input to the variable and make the program stop printing the same large value.
If it is any help, I am using Codeblocks.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is really `&days`? What are you really printing? What do the *address-of* (a.k.a. the *pointer-to*) operator `&` do?

Comment: I was meaning to print the value of the variable, and I didn't realzie that I included the ampersand where it did not need to be. Thank you for asking for clarification, I now understand my issue thanks to you and Sajid who answered my question

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the address of the variable...
Here is the fix:

```
printf("%d\n", days);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JayPatel "I can't believe I didn't realize that." --> That is not for you to realize or not as a programmer.  Such trivial errors are caught with a compiler well enabled.  Enable all compile warnings or seek a new compiler.  You will save time.  Unless you want yourself to be a compiler.